# How to concatenate all messages together in order of sequence in XSL?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

Assume i get the below XML:

```
<Gift>
            <GiftWrapId>026272275</GiftWrapId>
            <ClientIItemId>191267166704</ClientIItemId>
            <GiftMessageSequence>1</GiftMessageSequence>
            <GiftMessageType>GIFT</GiftMessageType>
            <GiftMessage>Happy Birthday, sweet</GiftMessage>
        </Gift>
        <Gift>
            <GiftWrapId>026272275</GiftWrapId>
            <ClientIItemId>191267166704</ClientIItemId>
            <GiftMessageSequence>2</GiftMessageSequence>
            <GiftMessageType>GIFT</GiftMessageType>
            <GiftMessage>Konnie</GiftMessage>
        </Gift>
```

I want the result to be 'Happy Birthday, sweet Konnie' but concatenating 'GiftMessage' in order of sequence as mentioned in 'GiftMessageSequence' tag:

```
<CommentInfo>
 <CommentType>X</CommentType>
  <xsl:element name="CommentText">
   <xsl:value-of select="*Happy Birthday, sweet Konnie should come here*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</CommentInfo>
```

Comment: Like many XSLT questions, the best solution varies between XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, and since both versions are in common use, you should always say which you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `<GiftMessageSequence>` has a numeric value, you can perform a sort on the node and then concatenate the value in `<GiftMessage>` to get the full message.

Wrapping the input XML in `<root>` nodes and applying the below XSLT on it, will give the required output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"  />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="message">
            <xsl:for-each select="Gift">
                <xsl:sort select="GiftMessageSequence" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(GiftMessage, ' ')" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <CommentInfo>
            <CommentType>X</CommentType>
            <CommontText>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($message)" />
            </CommontText>
        </CommentInfo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<CommentInfo>
    <CommentType>X</CommentType>
    <CommontText>Happy Birthday, sweet Konnie</CommontText>
</CommentInfo>
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to modify a bit to make it work with my existing code but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As your source includes multiple `Gift` tags, they must be
contained in some *root* tag (in order to form proper XML).

Then, in **XSLT 2.0**, the script can be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CommentInfo>
      <CommentType>X</CommentType>
      <CommentText>
        <xsl:variable name="msg">
          <xsl:for-each select="*/Gift">
            <xsl:sort select="GiftMessageSequence"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$msg/Gift//GiftMessage"/>
      </CommentText>
    </CommentInfo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`msg` variable gathers all `Gift` elements, sorting them by
`GiftMessageSequence`.
Note that the *XPath* expression starts from `*` to match **any** root tag name.

`value-of` instruction in **XSLT 2.0** prints values of **all** selected tags, with default separator equal to a space.